# How to exclude vendor module peerDependencies from export in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-material

## Question

When exporting a bundle in Webpack, how can I exclude 3rd-party module's peerDependency? (not 3rd-party module itself)

## Background

I would like to create an UIkit with customized components on top of `angular-material` framework. With Webpack, I can bundle my customzied components and angular-material together into something like `uikit.js`, and then port to other application later on. However, I don't want to include `angular` module itself into this `uikit.js`.

## Issue

It seems that Webpack is "clever" enough to notice that `angular` module is a dependency of `angular-material` module, and thus would export both `angular` module and `angular-material` module to the bundle. One can either use `config.externals: {'angular': 'angular'}` or `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/angular$/)` to exclude `angular` module which are explicitly require in the app, but for peerDependency (i.e. the one require inside `angular-material`), it would still include it.

So, how could I exclude this 3rd-party depended modules out from export?

### Example:

```
// app.js
var angular = require('angular');
var material = require('angular-material');

// ... other application logic    

// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // some module loaders
    ]
  },

  // This only excludes the angular module require by the app, not the one require by the angular-material
  externals: {'angular': 'angular'},

  plugins: [
    // This is the same as externals, only the one required by app.js would be excluded
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/angular$/)
  ]
};
```

Comment: Have you found a solution, @kavare?

Answer (score 1):

In the webpack (version 4) config, I export vendor apps into a vendor bundle and chunk all like this:

```
entry: {
  app: './app.js',
  vendor: [ 'angular', 'angular-material', '...' ],
},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
  }
},
```

Basically, this  indicates which chunks will be selected for optimization and `all` means that chunks can be shared even between async and non-async chunks.  Furthermore, How your modules are built and how you handle dependancies can further streamline your chunk size.

In addition you can provide a function whose return value will indicate whether to include each chunk:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks (chunk) {
        // exclude `my-excluded-chunk`
        return chunk.name !== 'my-excluded-chunk';
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a [link to webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunks-chunks) explaining the splitChunks plugin.